# How to change ordering of 'CurrentCellChanged' and 'SelectedCellsChanged' effects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid

When selecting a new cell on a new row in a WPF DataGrid, it seems that this is done through two sequential events that take path "A" in the figure below. These are the following events:

1. `CurrentCellChanged` (for shifting the selection within a current row)
2. `SelectedCellsChanged` (for shifting the selection of rows)

[image: Diagram of the paths a selected cell could take to the final selection]

Due to some background actions that I have going on with the DataGrid and its bound DataTable, I need to be able to mimic something like taking path "B". I can't find any other events that are triggered when clicking the next cell that allow me to do this.

Does anyone have any idea what I could do here?

I have one idea that should work, but it seems like a hack and I imagine there must be a better way that works with the DataGrid and not around it.

**Additional Info**

I am doing a sort of independent row-by-row cell selection marker, so I use `CurrentCellChanged` to perform an action if a user changes a selection within a row to a cell that meets certain criteria. However, if the selection is on a  different column of another row, the action is still first performed on the deselected row, and then again on the newly selected row once `SelectedCellsChanged` occurs.

If path "B" were taken, my setup would work correctly.

For now I'm using the following method to avoid this problem:

1. When the `CurrentCellChanged` event causes a change in markers on a row, a private boolean property of the form is set to record 'True' for a changed event, and some before & after values for one of the changes is also recorded.
2. If the `SelectedCellsChanged` event occurs, the routine checks for this boolean flag. If it indicates a change, the actions in `CurrentCellChanged` are reversed for the appropriate row using the recorded data before the action is then done in `SelectedCellsChanged`. Since as far as I can tell `SelectedCellsChanged` never occurs alone and always follows `CurrentCellChanged`, so this method should be reliable (famous last words).

Sorry for the lack of code, but it seems to me that the drawing and event names should suffice for describing the strategy that I need! If code samples would help, I can provide some if you indicate just what you need to see.

Comment: Your approach appears very sensible. Just clean the "intermediate state" as soon as you receive any other event

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".